# Adapt code from experimental ADAL build to the newest ADAL build

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office365, office365api

I was using the **[Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)** Nuget package for authentication to **Outlook.com** API, however, like a month ago all the members defined in `OutlookServicesClient.Me` drastically stopped working for unknown reason (like: `OutlookServicesClient.Me.MailFolders.Where(predicate).ExecuteSingleAsync()`) throwing a kind of server petition failed error message with no useful info, so for that reason I would like to try the regular library: **[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)** to see whether it automatically can solve the issue just by using that, instead of trying to use the experimental build.

The problem I have is trying to migrate the next code below, which is based on the syntax of the experimental build. I didn't found any overload for the `AcquireTokenAsync` function on which I can specify the **Outlook** scopes, and I didn't found other way to do it, also the first parameter of the `AcquireTokenAsync` function expects a `resource` string param that I'm not sure what I must put there.

I seen the official and 3rd party examples of using `AcquireTokenAsync` but I'm confused trying to adapt them, because the `resource` param or other things that I'm not sure how they work, also, much of the examples I seen are for **ASP.NET**, but I'm using **Windows Forms**.

---

This is the code that I need to migrate/update to the new ADAL syntax and method overloads:

**VB.NET** version (original code)

```
Dim scopes As String() = {
    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read",
    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite",
    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.send"
}

Dim cache As New TokenCache()
Dim authContext As New AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", cache)
Dim authResult As AuthenticationResult = 
    Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes, Nothing, "*Client ID*",
                                        New Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
                                        New PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto))

Dim client As New OutlookServicesClient(New Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), 
                                        Function() Task.FromResult(Me.authResult.Token))
```

**C#** version (untested online translation)

```
string[] scopes = {
    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read",
    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite",
    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.send"
};

TokenCache cache = new TokenCache();

AuthenticationContext authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", cache);

AuthenticationResult authResult = 
    Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes, null, "*Client ID*", 
                                        new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"), 
                                        new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));

OutlookServicesClient client = 
    new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), 
                              () => Task.FromResult(authResult.Token));
```

---

This is my translation intent, it is not working first because I don't know where to set the three **Outlook** scope urls, and secondlly because when I accept the Microsoft's permission web form it says that it cannot be processed due to an invalid request. (I set to `Nothing`/`nul` the `resource` param)

**VB.NET** version (original code)

```
Dim cache As New TokenCache()
Dim authContext As New AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", cache)
Dim authResult As AuthenticationResult = 
    Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource???, "*Client ID*", 
                                        New Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
                                        New PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto))

Dim client As New OutlookServicesClient(New Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), 
                                        Function() Task.FromResult(authResult.AccessToken))
```

**C#** version (untested online translation)

```
TokenCache cache = new TokenCache();

AuthenticationContext authContext = 
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common", cache);

AuthenticationResult authResult = 
    Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource???, "*Client ID*", 
                                        new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"), 
                                        new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));

OutlookServicesClient client = 
    new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), 
                              () => Task.FromResult(authResult.AccessToken));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the V2 endpoint to authenticate the client app, we can use the MSAL liabrary.

Here is an example for your reference:

Install the package through NuGet:
`Install-Package Microsoft.Identity.Client -pre`

Sample code to retrieve the token:

```
   public static async void GetToken()
    {
        string clientId = "0cfa4d3e-db48-400f-9b44-901cd5975312";
        var app = new PublicClientApplication(clientId);
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            string[] scopes = {
                    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read",
                    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite",
                    "https://outlook.office.com/mail.send"
                };

            result = await app.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Token);
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

And [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-wpf/) is an detail sample to Add sign-in to a Windows Desktop app.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I'm not understanding what you are telling me to do while `Microsoft.Identity.Client` is a different namespace and library than `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` and I was using the `AuthenticationContext` class to connect to **https://login.microsoftonline.com/common** but that class seems is not defined in the library that you mentioned.

Comment: More than that, I don't understand why Microsoft releases various libraries that seems they have the same purpose in fact, what a confussion all that is producing me, I just would like to adapt the code above, not to replace the entire library to learn new usage new methods and their syntax and their params etc.

Comment: Using the token that I receive with your code, It throws me a exception with error message **Resource not found for the segment 'Folders'** using a simple call like this: `Dim folders As IPagedCollection(Of IFolder) = Await client.Me.Folders.ExecuteAsync()` of the `Microsoft.OData` lib. Now I'm getting another error message: "**OData requests is not supported**", but not supported by what thing, MSAL?, I'm confussed.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I am having the same question you had 1.5yrs ago. How did you solve it?

Comment: @casaout Here I'll provide a full solution written in VB.NET. It consist in two enumerations and a "client" class that connect/login to Outlook account and supports basic generic usage operations like getting mail folder names, delete messages, etc, well, the thing is in that class you can check for an `AuthorizeAsync` function. https://pastebin.com/KtDjfciu + https://pastebin.com/RGDH8NjC + https://pastebin.com/8bU8689Q

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I finally decided to drop ADAL and use MSAL (even though it's still experimental for WPF)..